# Python Pandas: How to pass two or more arguments/ column-values to a custom function using .apply ()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

[image: The Data Set looks like this]

I am trying to write a custom function which takes 3 inputs and is basically checking the length of Full Name(First+Last) > Occupation.I have tries 2 variations of apply but both are giving an error. PS I am rookie in Python and Pandas area.

```
def check(fname,lname,occu):
if(len(fname)+len(lname)>len(occu)):
    return True
else:
    return False

customers.apply(lambda x: check(x['First Name'],x['Last Name'],x['Occupation']),axis=1)
```

[image: Error]
[image: Error for another variation]

Comment: You are trying to call lname(lname) when I assume you mean len(lname)

Comment: @scomes that resolved the issue for ```{customers.apply(lambda x: check(x['First Name'],x['Last Name'],x['Occupation']),axis=1)}```

but for ```customers['New Col'] = customers[['First Name','Last Name','Occupation']].apply(check,axis=1)```

I have this issue still persistent, is it a wrong way to implement `apply` when having multiple arguments?

Comment: Yes, that is the wrong way to implement apply when having multiple arguments. Your first method is one of the correct ways to do it

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post. The same reasons apply to exeptions and stacktraces - use text.

Answer (score 2):

The *immediate* error is probably a typo, i.e. you need `len(lname)` rather than `lname(lname)`. But you don't *need* a row-wise loop. You can call [`pd.Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) instead:

```
df['CheckFlag'] = (df['First Name'].str.len() + df['Last Name'].str.len()) > \
                  df['Occupation'].str.len()
```